"XML DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature set to true"
I'm encountering an issue while running mvn, where I'm getting the error message "XML DOCTYPE is disallowed when the feature set to true". I'm unsure about how to resolve this.
Here's the error message I'm seeing:
DOCTYPE ist nicht zulässig, wenn das Feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" auf "true" gesetzt ist.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the
How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to
reproduce the issue. See also How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.
